# Help with a (simple) log-linearisation

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, functions, economics

As a solution to an economic model, I end up with the following equation:
$$L=\frac{\alpha f^{\epsilon}s\left [ 1-Ak(1-\alpha+\alpha f^{\epsilon}s)^{\frac{1}{\epsilon}} f^{-1} s^\frac {-1}{\epsilon}\right ]}{\left [ 1-\alpha(1+f^{\epsilon}s) \right ]}$$

Is there any way to simplify it further and make it more readable, e.g. by differentiation or log-linearisation? How would it become in the latter case using the approximation that $ln(1+x)\approx x$?

I thank in advance anyone who takes a minute to help me.

Comment: What's the primary variable here?

Comment: f, s and k. $\alpha$ is a parameter.

Comment: To simplify the expression, first of all, you may use one letter to replace $f^\epsilon s$, such as let $y=f^\epsilon s$.